# MULTIPLICATION IN VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the data like

```
50  3.3
50  3.3
50  3.3
50  3.3
50  3.3
```

and I want this data in given below format

```
-50 3300
-50 3300
-50 3300
-50 3300
-50 3300
```

and I am using the code

```
Sub main()
    Dim data As Variant
    Dim iData As Long, datum As Long, iRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    With Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        data = .Resize(, 4).Value
        iData = LBound(data)

                .Cells(iRow).Offset(, 3).Value = .Cells(iRow).Offset(, 3).Value * 1000
                .Cells(iRow, UBound(data, 2) - 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Min(50, datum)
                datum = datum - 50
            Loop
            iData = iData + 1
        Loop While iData <= UBound(data)
        .Resize(1, 4).Copy
        .Resize(iRow, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I assume this is **not** VB.Net - I removed the tag but you can add it back again if it actually is VB.Net and not VBA as it appears to be.

Comment: Your code doesn't look complete (there seems to be a bit missing between `iData = LBound(data)` and `.Cells(iRow).Offset(, 3).Value = .Cells(iRow).Offset(, 3).Value * 1000`) - can you please check to ensure that you copied everything into the question.